# Merge elements in tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

Here I have a dataset:

```
rd='''
1:A,B,C;D,E
2:F,G
3:H,J,K
'''
```

Desired result:

```
[('A','B'),('B',C'),('A','C'),('D','E'),('F','G'),('H','J'),('J','K'),('H','K')]
```

My code:

```
def rd_edges(f):
    allEdges =[]
    for line in f.split():
        edges =line.split(":")[1].split(';')
        for edge in edges:
            i =0
            j =1
            for i in len(edge):
                for j in len(edge):
                    i <j
                    j +=1
                    if j >len(edge):
                        end
                i +=1
                if i >len(edge)-1:
                    end
            allEdges.append(edge(i),edge(j))       

    return allEdges
```

I know the `itertools` module can solve this problem, but want to write a function to transfer the data into a tuple without importing any modules. I reviewed some past questions posted on the forum, but am still confused about doing this.

Comment: `end`?? You mean `return`

Comment: @idjaw it is not the same expected output.

Comment: Yes. I can see that too...All the questions seemed very similar. But this is still lacking more information for the OP to be more explicit about what is failing in their code.

Comment: Please provide a better [mcve] of your problem indicating what exactly is not working in your code as you expect.

Comment: Between `C` & `D`, I think it should be  `,` instead of `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it without import of itertools:

```
def rd_edges(f):
    allEdges =[]
    for line in f.split():
        edges = line.split(":")[1].split(';')
        for edge in edges:
            nodes = edge.split(',')
            for i, a in enumerate(nodes):
                for b in nodes[i+1:]:
                    allEdges.append((a,b))
    return allEdges

rd='''
1:A,B,C;D,E
2:F,G
3:H,J,K
'''
print (rd_edges(rd))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simplified solution to achieve it using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) and [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) functions. In order to flatten the list, I am using [`operator.add()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add) with [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function:

```
import re
from itertools import combinations
from operator import add
rd='''
1:A,B,C;D,E
2:F,G
3:H,J,K
'''
my_aplhalist = (re.compile('(\n\d:)').split(rd.rstrip()))[2::2]
my_combinations = [list(combinations(item.split(','), 2)) for item_str in my_aplhalist for item in item_str.split(';')]
my_solution = reduce(add, my_combinations)
# Value of 'my_solution': [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('D', 'E'), ('F', 'G'), ('H', 'J'), ('H', 'K'), ('J', 'K')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Roughly equivalent to" code from the docs of the itertools function you have been wisely advised to use shows a correct version that is actually written in Python:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_edges(f):    
    out = []
    for line in f.split():
      line = line.split(':')[1]
      disjoint = line.split(';')
      for d in disjoint:
        s = d.split(',')
        for i, node in enumerate(s)):
          for downnode in s[i+1:]:
            out.append((node, downnode))
    return out
```

This works, but gives out put in a different order.  If you care about that, you have to start at the end of the list of nodes and build towards it.